# grails: how to save a domain objects in bootstrap and avoid duplication by ignoring unique constraint errors?

Tags: grails, bootstrapping

We have a lot of data created in the bootstrap.
if you just do

```
 def foo = new Foo(bar:"hello").save(failOnError:true)
```

and you start the app in a context such as test which has "dbCreate = "update"
and bar has to be unique, then you will get an error as it tries to create 2 copies of the same piece of data.

just calling save() without failOnError solves the problem partially, as now it creates the object in the DB if it was not there, and ignores it if it was already there (assuming there is at least one unique constraint to protect the object).

However, this is not tenable, as it doesn't tell you if there was another error, such as this:

```
def foo = new Foo(barTypo:"hello").save()
```

and you end up without the piece of data in the DB and the app falls over in unexpected ways.

The long winded solution is to do a find before every save:

```
def foo = Foo.findByBar("hello")?: new Foo(bar:"hello").save(failOnError:true)
```

However, I was trying to find a way less verbose.

I tried this:

```
saveIgnoreDups(new foo(bar:"hello"))

def saveIgnoreDups(ob) {
    try {
        ob.save(failOnError: true)
    } catch(org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        // fail silently - was already there.
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work: the catch does not catch unique integrity constraint failures.

I am sure there is an easy way to do this, but don't know where to find it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Learn to use `.validate()`, and validate your classes before trying to save them. In the case of a duplicate you will get a validation error: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/validate.html

Comment: thanks Joshua. I tried the validation route, but  I could not find any documentation on how to detect any unique constraint, as opposed to other error types.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you investigate using `.validate()` to verify your domain class instances are *valid* before trying to save them.

For example:

```
// Bootstrap.groovy
def foo = new Foo(bar:"hello")
if (foo.validate()) {
  foo.save()
} else {
 // maybe do something? maybe not. up to you.
}
```

The above call to `.vaidate()` will ensure that your `Foo` is valid for any constraints you have defined (e.g. unique `bar`).

Comment: Thanks Joshua, but this is the same as calling save(), i.e. it will ignore ALL errors, I only want to ignore the specific case of unique constraint violations, and throw an exception in any other type of error case.  Sadly, I cant find any documentation on what errors can be tested for.

Comment: Perhaps you may want to look at `findOrSaveWhere` then. http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findOrSaveWhere.html

Comment: If you use the `validate` technique, `foo` will then have an errors object in it if it doesn't validate properly.  From there you should be able to check for a unique constraint and throw a new exception if any other type exists using a `foo.errors.each{`.   I haven't explored the errors extensively myself, but that should allow you to check for unique, and if it isn't unique you can throw an exception manually, or whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like this:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(barTypo: "hello").save()

boolean hasTypoError = foo.hasErrors() && foo.errors.hasFieldError("barType")
boolean hasUniqueError = hasTypoError && foo.errors.getFieldError("barTypo").find {
    it.code == "default.not.unique.message" || it.code.contains("unique")
}

if (hasUniqueError ) {
    // your code 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Joshuas suggestion:

```
 def foo = Foo.findOrSaveWhere(bar:"hello")
```

seems to solve the data creation problem nicely: it inserts the row if it is not there, reads it if it is there (a bonus), and, most importantly, throws an exception if there is a field error, typo or similar (like having failOnError:true)

EDIT- it does not catch missing required params, and silently does not save the object, so back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. Begin with a method (or as in my example a closure):

```
def saveIgnoreDups = {Class c, Map properties -> 
    c.withNewSession {
        c.newInstance(properties).save(failOnError: true)
    }
}
```

The first parameter is the domain class, and the second is the property/values you want to initialize the instance with. It's used like this:

```
def a = saveIgnoreDups(Foo, [bar:"hello"])
def b = saveIgnoreDups(Foo, [bar:"hello"])
```

In this example, *b* will fail to save and throw a *grails.validation.ValidationException*.